# Set Dropdownlist Selected Value in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to set the setectedValue of a DropDownList using razor, but because it's a list used several times in the same page, I can't set the selected value in the Controller, so how can I set it in the View?

Actual Controller List code:

```
ViewBag.CargaTipos = new SelectList(db.CargaTipos, "Id", "Nome").OrderBy(c => c.Text);
```

Actual View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.CargaTipo.Id, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CargaTipos)
```

Models:

```
[Table("Cargas")]
public class Carga
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CargaTipo")]
    public int CargaTipo_Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tipo de Carga")]
    public virtual CargaTipo CargaTipo { get; set; }
}

[Table("CargaTipos")]
public partial class CargaTipo
{
    public CargaTipo()
    {
        this.Cargas = new HashSet<Carga>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Carga> Cargas { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cannot set `SelectedValue` property outside constructor of `SelectedList` class. Use this instead

```
ViewBag.CargaTipos = db.CargaTipos;
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.CargaTipo.Id,new SelectList(ViewBag.CargaTipos,"Id","Nome",YOUR_SELECTED_VALUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use documented behavior of Html.DropDownListFor<> like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => modelItem.CargaTipo_Id,
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CargaTipos)
```

Pay attention on using declared variable in expression. In your case it is **modelItem**.
And you have to use CargaTipo_Id from main model, not Id from referened model.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I get "CargaTipo" underlined, maybe because it's in a foreach (var item in Model.Cargas) ?

Comment: For collections use @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Collection), don't use the foreach iterator. Create strongly typed view in EditorTemplates folder named like collection item class name. There is you can use normal syntax for DropDownListFor method.

Comment: To iterate all the Cargas? Any example link to check?

Comment: Yes. In your case for hidden iterate all Cargas `EditorFor` is applicable method. [For example](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/).

Comment: I'm familiar with EditorFor but not in the List context.

Comment: It's good functionality on `EditorFor` method. If there is a collection returned by expression from method's parameter that method will iterate received collection and render template for each element.
In your case for hidden iterate all Cargas `EditorFor` is applicable method. [For example](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/). If your view receive something like `IEnumerable<Carga>` you can use also `EditorForModel` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430917(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do it with some `JQuery` code(you can also use JavaScript depending of you), but I advice `JQuery`. So you will need to reference link of `JQuery lib` in your Layout

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
      {
        $("idOfyourDropDownList option[value=Id]').attr('selected','selected');

       })
     </script>
```

I think when you put this script on your solution, by default you will have item selected by default.

I hope it will help

Comment: Hi thanks but I prefer not using jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
  {
    $("#idOfyourDropDownList option[value=Id]").attr('selected','selected');

   })
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**